# How to increase the time out interval of XMPP socket in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp

Please let me know how to increase the time out interval. 
My app always gives me connection stream exception after some interval. Is there anything needs to be done explicitly in XMPP framework ?

Comment: You need to activate `XMPPPing` module and enable `respondsToQueries`

Comment: Thank you,will try this and check this out.

Comment: Am trying to use +- (BOOL)connectWithTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout error:(NSError **)errPtr; and referring https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/.Any suggestion for infinite timeout value set up for above function. ?

Comment: That function is not related to stream disconnection. Use XMPPPing module as I wrote first.

Comment: Vitalyster, Let me try that out. Do you suggest me some sample tutorial links which has XMPPPing examples ? I am very new to XMPP and appreciate your help.